# What if a king is also a duke in a different kingdom?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I play as the King of Ireland (and Castille), and I've betrothed my male heir to the heir of a duchy and some stray counties in England. As I understand it, my daughter-in-law will rule as a duchess on her own, but their heir will rule both my kingdoms and the English lands (as they are of my dynasty).

However, the English lands are of course subjects of England. So what happens then? Will the duchy and counties be separated from England and become part of Ireland? Or will I become a vassal of England – and if so, to what extent?

Comment: This has happened in history often enough that there is a technical term for it: [personal union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_union). Short version: a personal union is two separate politicial entities with their own laws and concerns, that share one ruler. They stay separate, politically. Personal unions rarely remained "united" after the person holding both titles died, but occasionally the separate political entities were more permanently joined during the time of personal union. (This is how the Holy Roman Empire of Germany formed.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie But the question here isn't what happens when two kingdoms have the same ruler, it's about a kingdom and a duchy in a separate kingdom having the same ruler.

Comment: @svick My summary is deliberately brief. Personal unions aren't limited to kingdoms (hence my use of "political entity"). Also, the distinction between a duchy and a kingdom is a matter of vassalage agreements, and isn't nearly as clear-cut as we modern people think of states. Since it's just an interesting footnote to the question, anyone who finds it interesting should most certainly read the full Wikipedia article, as my brief summary is definitely insufficient. :)

Comment: @svick For a real world example: The Kingdom of the Netherlands and the Grand Duchy of Luxembourg were in a personal union from 1815 till 1890, reigned by 3 male rulers in a row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

King can never be a vassal of another king, and there is no “partial vassal” or something like that (and the same applies to all the other levels too).

The duchy will become part of your kingdom (de facto, this won't change which kingdom it is part of de jure). But if the crown authority in the other kingdom is high enough, you won't get the duchy (it prevents titles to pass out of the realm through inheritance).

Comment: Aha, I see. If the crown authority is set to "high" or "max", I will actually not inherit the lands (I assume they will be automatically revoked by the king). Is there a way to see crown laws of a different country, without loading the game as its ruler?

Comment: @Nix Yeah, you can see them in the “De jure kingdoms” map mode. Not sure if there is another way.

Comment: I posted a follow-up question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/105834/invading-a-country-with-high-crown-laws