# Invading a country with high crown laws

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I play as the King of Ireland, and I plan to expand a little in the Kingdom they call England. Problem is, they have high crown authority, meaning any landed titles can not be inherited outside their realm. If I gain a dukal title, this will not be inherited to my heir upon my death. So how do I go about this?

I have a few ideas:

- Play like a baws and challenge the crown directly. This will be hard, because I need to
  control at least half the country, and it might be hard to conjure up
  that many CBs before I die. **Even then, can I lower the crown authority when it's
  not my main title?**
- Give away all my English lands to a dynasty member (preferably my
  heir) before I die. In theory, this would give me more time to build
  up an English powerbase.
- Ignore England for now, and focus on Scotland and Wales. When those
  are secured, I could possibly start pushing for an Emperor title.
- Have the English king excommunicated, which may give me a free CB (right?) –
  however, this is highly unlikely in my situation.

My second problem is, even if I did manage to become King of England and change their crown authority, my sources inform me their succession law is actually *seniority* – so that would need to be changed as well, and as far as I know, you can't change two crown laws in one reign.

Seriously, those bastards make it hard for me to invade their lands. It's almost as if they don't want me there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it doesn't work that way. The title can't pass outside the realm though inheritance. But after you gain the duchy, the title will be outside of the realm, so it can stay there, even if you die.

Comment: I don't quite understand. It sounds contrary to what you said in your other answer http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/104498/25281 What good is the "no titles outside realm" then? Does it mean that if I conquer it, it will be okay, but if I married an English landowner, it would not be passed on to her non-dynastic heir?

Comment: @Nix Yes, that's what it means.

Answer (score 7):

Bit late perhaps but the good of it is that there are several ways to lose titles. Your way is through conquering the title of one of your neighbours. A duchy or a county which you claim by right of power - Your army beats his. That way you FORCE the title to pass outside of the High Crown Authority realm, and add it to your own.

High/Max crown authority only prevents titles from being lost through -inheritence-. Say a countess has a title and she marries someone (not matrilineally) outside of your Kingdom. (Countess of Norfolk marries the King of France for example). When she has children, they would inherit the King's title, and become King of France, but they would also get her title (Norfolk) and that would become a part of France: because as King of France the heir could hold it in his own right. High crown authority prevents this. When the Countess in this scenario dies, her title wouldn't go to the children of the King of France, but simply revert back to the King of England instead.

Comment: Thanks Keden, and welcome to Arqade. Yes, you are correct. It is essentially what svick said in his answer, although your explanation is more detailed.